# Cannot build XMP-Toolkit-SDK

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio, sdk, xmp

I'm trying to use Adobe XMP-Toolkit-SDK (it's written with C++) with Visual Studio (VB.net) to build a project to EDIT the METADATA of PDFs.

But I couldn't build or deal with the SDK yet.
Can anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Can you ask a slightly more specific question please? I don't think anyone will be able to answer this unless you give us some more specifics about what you've tried, what you're confused about, etc.

Comment: i don't know how to get XMP-Toolkit-SDK to work with Visual Studio and vb.net that's my problem .. thank you

Comment: This isn't the place to come to ask for tutorials. There are lots of other forums where you might ask for a step by step guide. Stack Overflow is for _specific_ questions.

Comment: im not askin for a tutorials , i just wondering if anyone had used it before and guide me through the start of it i searched for it but there is no results or tutorials anywhere .